# How to proof $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(w_1*t)\sin(w_2*t)\,dt = 0$ if $w_1 \neq w_2$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, orthogonality

In my math script (signal theory) it says that two functions are orthogonal to each other when $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}s^\star(t)u(t)\,dt = 0$. Now I want to prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(w_1*t)\sin(w_2*t)\,dt = 0$$ applies when $w_1 \neq w_2$ applies. No matter what I try to do, I always get the problem that I have to solve the integral of a sine or cosine from minus infinity to plus infinity, which makes no sense. How can I solve the problem?

EDIT:
* means complex conjugation.

Comment: What is $\star$ and $\ast$?

Comment: You can't prove this because it's not true. Because the integral in question simply does not exist.

Comment: That would be true if your integration interval was $[0,2\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $w_1,w_2$ were integers.

Comment: Have you tried writing your product of sines as a difference of cosines, or the real part of the difference of complex exponentials?

Comment: Tweaking @GReyes's comment:  and if $w_1 \not= \pm w_2$.

Comment: Michael, where does this problem come from? Is it an assignment question, or is it 'just' an assertion that you feel should be true?

Comment: My professor's script says that if two functions are orthogonal to each other, the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}s^\star(t)u(t)\,dt = 0$ must result in zero. Then the script claims that the above two functions $sin(w_1*t)$ and $sin(w_2*t)$ are orthogonal to each other if $w_1\neq w_2$. Unfortunately, nothing more is said about this. I wanted to check that out.